# Overheating car

Tags: overheating, jeep, patriot

I have a 2009 Jeep Patriot Sport. So I noticed a couple of months ago that my car started overheating. When i opened the trunk i noticed that there was anti-freeze everywhere but I didn’t know where it was coming from. Someone told me that the radiator cap was faulty so i went and changed it but the overheating didn’t stop. I took my car to many different mechanics and they told me that they didn’t know what was causing the overheating. I decided to get all the antifreeze removes and to replace the water pump, thermostat, and the radiator. The car looked good for a few days but then it overheated again and now there’s a smell of antifreeze everytime i turn on the AC and no one knows what the problem is.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!  Sounds like you might want to get your heater core looked at.

Comment: You must be surrounded by inept mechanics unable to troubleshoot a cooling system leak. You or a reputable repair shop can use a special cooling system tester; adapters to fit most radiator caps, coolant containers using pressurized caps and a hand held air pump with gauge to pressurize a system. With a cold engine, antifreeze leaks can be found without being scalded by hot coolant.

Comment: I agree with F Dryer. Heck, AutoZone has a coolant pressure tester kit in their free tool loaner program. Why not borrow that kit and look for the leak yourself. And start looking at the heater core under the dashboard, behind the glove box. You will find your leak in minutes.